# Process substitution with pv results in empty file

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I am having issues getting the `pv` command to work with `tar` using Bash process substitution.

I can use `pv` like this, and it works:

```
$ tar cvf - dir | pv > file.tar
dir/
dir/b
dir/a
  10KiB 0:00:00 [16.9MiB/s] [<=>                                 ]
$ ls -s file.tar 
12 file.tar
```

Using process substitution with `cat` also works:

```
$ tar cvf >(cat > file.tar) dir
dir/
dir/b
dir/a
$ ls -s file.tar 
12 file.tar
```

But this command results in an empty `file.tar`:

```
$ tar cvf >(pv > file.tar) dir
dir/
dir/b
dir/a
$ ls -s file.tar 
0 file.tar
```

I have also tried `tar cvf >(pv - > file.tar) dir` with the same result.

My goal is to have `pv` print out progress, and pipe the output of `tar` (i.e., the list of files and any errors) to other commands for additional processing. The first example command above only results in 2 output streams: `stdout` contains the binary tar data, and `stderr` contains both the list of files and any error messages. Using process substitution will result in 3 output streams: the binary tar data goes to the new process, `stdout` contains the list of files, and `stderr` contains any error messages.

Can I use the `pv` command with Bash process substitution, and if so, how?

I am using `pv 1.6.0` and `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release`.

Interestingly, if I use `strace` to try and debug `pv`, it works:

```
$ tar cvf >(strace pv > file.tar) dir
dir/
dir/b
dir/a
execve("/usr/bin/pv", ["pv"], [/* 75 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1eb8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9bac000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=123417, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 123417, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f46c9b8d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1864888, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3967392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f46c95c0000
mprotect(0x7f46c977f000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f46c997f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bf000) = 0x7f46c997f000
mmap(0x7f46c9985000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9985000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9b8c000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9b8b000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9b8a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f46c9b8b700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f46c997f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f46c9bae000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f46c9b8d000, 123417)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1eb8000
brk(0x1ed9000)                          = 0x1ed9000
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=73, ws_col=178, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {0x408690, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x408660, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, {0x408710, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x408620, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x408640, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x408640, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x408640, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, {SIG_IGN, [SYS], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
geteuid()                               = 4841
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=110592, ...}) = 0
msgget(0x500112e9, IPC_CREAT|0600)      = 2818048
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7ffc1cd79860)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 29280
msgrcv(2818048, 0x7ffc1cd797e0, 568, 29280, IPC_NOWAIT) = -1 ENOMSG (No message of desired type)
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f46c9b69000
select(1, [0], [], NULL, {0, 90000})    = 1 (in [0], left {0, 89998})
splice(0, NULL, 1, NULL, 131072, SPLICE_F_MORE) = 10240
select(1, [0], [], NULL, {0, 90000})    = 1 (in [0], left {0, 89999})
splice(0, NULL, 1, NULL, 131072, SPLICE_F_MORE) = 0
read(0, "", 131072)                     = 0
write(2, "  10KiB 0:00:00 [  37MiB/s] [  <"..., 178  10KiB 0:00:00 [  37MiB/s] [  <=>                                                                                                                                               ]) = 178
)                       = 1
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(0)                                = 0
msgctl(2818048, IPC_RMID, 0x7ffc1cd79b30) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f46c95f54b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
munmap(0x7f46c9b69000, 135168)          = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

$ ls -s file.tar 
12 file.tar
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve that is not achieved by the first usage in your question. Does your first usage not take the output of tar, report progress, and send stdout to the next step in the pipeline (which in your example is a redirection)? Seems to me that process substitution is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @ghoti see my edit above

Comment: This is fishy. I have tried your command `tar cvf >(pv > file.tar) dir` and it worked perfectly on a Debian jessie with `tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1`, `pv 1.5.7` and `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)`. I suspect a bug in your version of `pv`.

Comment: @Dario, that is very interesting. I built `pv 1.5.7` [from source](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/sources/pv-1.5.7.tar.gz) and got the same result. When you run it on your computer, file.tar is not empty?

Comment: what happens for `tar cvf >(pv | cat > file.tar) dir`?